# How can I get the alert in my Pinscript V2 to pull the "comment" from my entry

Tags: tradingview-api

Using WunderTrading bot and it requires the comment in the strategy.entry to be sent to them (via the webhook)  I have a V2 script that I want to use but the alert (which has the required {{strategy.order.comment}} in the message) is only displaying the ID and not the comment.
Not familiar with V2 and cant update this script. Is there a way to force the alert to display (push) the comment and not the ID?

Tried updating to V3 and does not produce the same results. Also, tried moving comment to beginning of entry parameters...but error expecting ID